# Pick().If() vs Where() in Windsor Castle

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

What's the difference between functions if() and where() in Windsor Castle.
I came across in code these two ways of component registration

1)

```
container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
                .Where(x=> x.IsClass && x.GetAllInterfaces().Length > 0)
                .WithService.AllInterfaces()
                .LifestyleSingleton());
```

2)

```
container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
                .Pick()
                .If(x=> x.IsClass && x.GetAllInterfaces().Length > 0)
                .WithService.AllInterfaces()
                .LifestyleSingleton());
```

I wonder what is the difference between these two ways of component registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code, you'll see that `Where` does (practically) the same thing as `Pick()`, additionally adding the call to `.If` internally. This is looking at the internal workings of the code, so it's not guaranteed that this won't change for whatever reason at some point.

`Where`:

```
public BasedOnDescriptor Where(Predicate<Type> accepted)
{
    var descriptor = new BasedOnDescriptor(typeof(object), this, additionalFilters).If(accepted);
    criterias.Add(descriptor);
    return descriptor;
}
```

And `Pick`:

```
public BasedOnDescriptor Pick()
{
    return BasedOn<object>();
}

public BasedOnDescriptor BasedOn<T>()
{
    return BasedOn(typeof(T));
}

public BasedOnDescriptor BasedOn(Type basedOn)
{
    var descriptor = new BasedOnDescriptor(basedOn, this, additionalFilters);
    criterias.Add(descriptor);
    return descriptor;
}
```